# package does not excist -intelij

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classpath, multi-module

I am working on a Spring Boot multi-module project, and everything was functioning well until I encountered the following error: 'package com.it.model does not exist'. Can anyone help me understand and resolve this issue?

I have been verifying the POM of the submodule as well as the parent POM, and everything seems to be in order. The dependency for my submodule's infrastructure, which includes the package 'com.it.model', is already present in the service's POM. I've tried invalidating the cache, rebuilding the project, and yet I'm still encountering the same problem. Any insights into resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Within the module system you are not allowed to have the same package in two modules. _A safety measure._